# Nginx: force SSL on one path, non-SSL on others

Tags: nginx, ssl

How do I set up Nginx conf file to force SSL on only one of the paths in my site and non-SSL on all the rest?

For example, I want all of the URLs under /user to be https but all the rest of the URLs to be http.

For the first part I have:

```
rewrite ^/user(.*) https://$http_host$request_uri?;
```

I don't want to use "if". I assume it would take advantage of order of operation but I don't want to end up in a loop.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In your nginx configuration, you should have two "server" areas.  One for port 80, and one for port 443 (non-SSL and SSL).   Simply add a location in your non-SSL website to redirect to your SSL page.

```
server {
    root /var/www/
    location / {
    }
    location /user {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

it will forward all traffic that ends up at /user to your https:// server.

Then, in your 443 server, you do the opposite.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    root /var/www/
    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    location /user {
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is good, but it falls into a couple of common [Pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls), specifically "Root inside location block" and "Taxing rewrites"

Comment: I edited. Does it look OK? I also took out listen 80 and added http_host.

Comment: With this configuration, the connection switches from/to ssl/non-ssl when a user navigate the pages on the site, ssl for urls started with `/user` and non-ssl for all other urls.  As a result, even user explicitly types `https://www.example.com/` in the address bar of the browser, the resulting page is `http://www.example.com/`.  Is there a way to implement the auto-url-rewrite between ssl/non-ssl as achieved by the settings described in this answer, but still respect the explicit ssl request if it's explicitly typed by user in the address bar?  Thanks!

Comment: @goodbyeera yeah. If the idea is to force users to use SSL in certain areas,  we can override their protocols there but honor them everywhere else by simply removing the rewrite commands from the 443 server configuration. Of course, now when they go to a secured part, they'll still be browsing with SSL when they go somewhere else, but it allows people to choose to use SSL from the get go.

Answer (score 13):

Nginx allows to process both HTTP and HTTPS within the same `server` block. Thus you don't have to duplicate directives for both and can redirect the path you want to secure

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ... ssl certificate and other configs ...

  location /user {
    if ($scheme = 'http') {
      rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
  }

  ... your basic configuration ...
}
```

Be sure **not** to put `ssl on` line there because it'll break plain HTTP.

Optionally, you can redirect all other requests from HTTPS back to HTTP the same way:

```
if ($scheme = 'https') {
  rewrite ^ http://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

**UPDATE**: as Alexey Ten kindly points out in comments section, checking `scheme` on each request is not a very bright idea. You should follow declarative way of configuring your nginx. In this case, declare two server blocks with redirects by `location`, move common logic to a separate file and `include` it in both. So GruffTech's answer is better.

Comment: It's ineffective to make nginx check scheme for every request.

Comment: I know the question was answered 3 years ago, but I found it while struggling to do what I gradually did and just wanted to share my results with people who will follow my steps.

Comment: Well, you should read http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: @AlexeyTen isn't it the case "when you can't avoid using an if"? Is there any other way to have same configuration for HTTP and HTTPS without duplicating directives?

Comment: It is. Two server blocks perfectly split requests without `if`

Comment: They do split requests, but the rest of the logic (passing to proxy, serving static, logging etc) should then be duplicated for both blocks, or am I missing something?

Comment: Use `include` directive for common directives. Some duplication is OK.

Comment: Okay, thanks Alexey! Probably I'll fight my Apache background and go the declarative path with two server blocks.