# Redirecting all traffic to HTTP except one URL

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, magento

I have been scratching my head off as all of the forums are saying that following simple code should work for redirecting all traffic from HTTPS to HTTP except one location ([Nginx: force SSL on one path, non-SSL on others](https://serverfault.com/questions/270339/nginx-force-ssl-on-one-path-non-ssl-on-others)) but in my case it is not working as expected

It is Magento site having following nginx configuration

```
upstream examplecombackend {
    server unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-examplecom.sock;
}

server {
    listen 111.11.111.111:80;

    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    access_log /home/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/error.log;
    root /home/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /checkout/ {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite / /index.php last;
        }
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   examplecombackend;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen 111.11.111.111:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    root /home/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location /checkout/ {
    }
}
```

Now, after doing this when I go to SSL https://example.com/ it correctly forwards to Non- SSL http://example.com/ but if I go to https://example.com/checkout it says

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.8.1
```

Not sure what I am missing here....

Comment: Not being familiar with magento: shouldn't you enable php on your https virtualhost?

Comment: /checkout/ is a single fixed URL and doesn't include urls such as /checkout/session=abc?def . Are you sure that is the only URL used? If not then you'll need to use a regular expression match.

Comment: @SYN yes you are correct I should need to add PHP handlers in 443 section too.

Comment: @Tim yes, it makes sense let me try that too...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I wouldn't make such a configuration myself. Having mixed `http` and `https` on the same site makes `https` security weaker and exposes your site to man-in-the-middle attacks.

However, here should be a working configuration for you if you really want to set up thing like this.

The main issue in your configuration is the missing definitions for PHP for your `/checkout` URI.

I would make a configuration like this. This also contains optimizations for your configuration:

```
upstream examplecombackend {
    server unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-examplecom.sock;
}

server {
    listen 111.11.111.111:80;

    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    access_log /home/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/error.log;
    root /home/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /checkout {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location ~ (.+\.php)/ {
        rewrite ^ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   examplecombackend;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen 111.11.111.111:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    root /home/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs;

    location /checkout {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   examplecombackend;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

Changes I did:

```
location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    expires 30d;
}
```

I removed the `@handler` location, because it is the same as if `index.php` was the last element of `try_files` directive.

```
location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}
```

I changed the regex capture to happen on the `location` level, therefore there is one regex match less happening on every request matching this location, since we can use simple `^` as the match condition in the `rewrite` directive.

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite / /index.php last;
        }
```

I added backslash escape to the `location` regex condition, because without backslash it would match for example `/path/to/aphp`, since `.` by itself matches any character.

I also removed the `if` test shown above from the block, because the same test happens already in the `try_files` directive earlier.

And finally, the fix to your actual issue:

In your `server` block for https stuff, I changed `location` blocks like this:

```
    location /checkout {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   examplecombackend;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

So, the `location /checkout` block tells nginx to rewrite all requests to `/index.php`, just like in `http` server block. Also the PHP processing `location` is the same as in `http` block.

However, there still might be issues with the links Magento creates, and the way requests get redirected between `http` and `https`. Cookie security settings is one thing that can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small change. The ~* should tell Nginx to case insensitive match any URL with /checkout/ in it, rather than just the precise URL /checkout/.

I'm a little rusty and I can't remember the precise location match order and syntax, but it's worth trying.

```
location ~* /checkout/ {
```

Comment: unfotunately that too is throwing `404 Not Found
nginx/1.8.1` means location directive has always been correct it's something other which may be directly related to Magento.

Comment: @Tim, nginx matches locations with simple prefixes just fine, you don't need to enable regex matching here.

Answer (score -1):

Conditional rewriting might help in your case:

```
server {
    listen 111.11.111.111:80;
    listen 111.11.111.111:443 ssl;   

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    access_log /home/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/error.log;

    root /home/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs;

    location / {
        if ($scheme = "https") {
            return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
            break;
        }
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    } 

    location /checkout/ {
        if ($scheme = "http") {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            break;
        }
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   examplecombackend;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue is that conditional forwarding makes much load on server and not recommended by nginx, do you see any other alternate than using if

Comment: The original approach is better, not using if. Follow up the reply there rather than using this IMHO.

Comment: @Tim Please read about _if_ [more throughly](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). It clearly says that this is _exactly_ the case it was designed for. There is no performance penalty if (only) return or rewrite are done inside of an _if_ block.

Comment: @Anubioz what is the difference if I use redirect instead of return under if statement?

Comment: @Tim What I see is that page which is secure has this URL https://www.example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/sessionID.... so what should be the regular expression for location directive?

Comment: From memory you just put a ~ between the location and the pattern : " location ~ /checkout/ ". You can do some reading, it's pretty simple.